# Using a compound literal to initialize a malloc'd buffer,

Tags: c, struct, initialization, malloc

Is there an easier way of writing:

```
rver_t *buf = malloc(sizeof(rver_t));
rver_t tmp = (rver_t) {.op=OP_RVER, .protocol_version=1};
memcpy(buf, tmp, sizeof(rver_t));
```

to initialise a malloc'd buffer with a struct?

Note: typedef happens in a header:

```
#define OP_RVER 1
typedef struct rver_s {
    uint32_t op;
    uint32_t protocol_version;
} rver_t;
```

Comment: I'd expect `*buf = (rver_t) {...};` to work just as well.

Comment: What's the whole point? The compound literal in your code serves _no_ other purpose but obfuscation. You are trying to solve a problem where these is no problem to solve. Just assign values directly to the members of buf. Then the code is optimal both in terms of readability and performance.

Comment: @Lundin: just assigning known members won't zero-init unknown ones. Compound literals or a named temp var are the **only** ways to do this. (`calloc` is not valid because it zeros the representation not the values)

Comment: The code as is doesn't work? EITHER declare tmp as a pointer:
   `rver_t *tmp = &((rver_t) {.op=OP_RVER, .protocol_version=1});`
OR take its address in the memcpy call:
   `memcpy(buf, &tmp, sizeof(rver_t));`
OR just do as Anton suggested:
   `*buf = (rver_t) {.op=OP_RVER, .protocol_version=1};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question but here an answer for the casual passerby.

Functional rewrite

```
rver_t *buf = memcpy(malloc(sizeof(rver_t)), &(rver_t) {.op=OP_RVER, .protocol_version=1}, sizeof(rver_t));
```

or write a macro that hides the combination

```
#define RVERALOC(a, b) memcpy(malloc(sizeof(rver_t)), &(rver_t){.op=(a), .protocol_version=(b)}, sizeof(rver_t));

rver_t *buf = RVERALOC(OP_RVER, 1);
```

The idea is to remember that the fact that `memcpy()` returns its first parameter (as does `memmove()`, `strcpy()` etc.).
Of course, one has to be aware that allocation errors will lead to undefined behaviour as the `NULL` as first parameter of `memcpy()` is not checked. On most hosts with memory protection it will crash with a segmentation fault which is often an acceptable behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You could type:

```
buf -> op = OP_EVER;
buf -> protocol_version = 1;
```